# Building and versioning on Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, versioning

I created an app long time ago using the last SDK on Mac Leopard, I upgrade to Snow Leopard and so now I use the new SDK and can build app for Iphone 3.1.3, I've got a problem now because I can't build my app on my OS Iphone device 3.1 or 3.1.2 
How can I change it and allow my app to aso build in older version beginning to 3.1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clean all Targets worked for me. ;)